# What version of Outlook 2013 supports ribbon bar buttons for Office Add-ins?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-2013, outlook-web-addins

When was support for ribbon bar buttons added to Outlook 2013? I'm unable to find any documentation that points to a proper version number.

I've found this link for "Adds support for Web Add-in commands to Outlook 2013.": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114829/ms16-029-description-of-the-security-update-for-outlook-2013-march-8,-2016

And also this link for the same thing "Adds Web Add-in commands support to Outlook 2013. 
": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114828/march-8,-2016,-update-for-office-2013-kb3114828

And also this update, stating "Adds Web Add-in commands support to Outlook 2013.
": https ://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114816/march-8,-2016,-update-for-office-2013-kb3114816 (defanged)

I'm guessing that this happened around mid-March, but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all three patches:

- Outlook Patch https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114829
- Mso Patch: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114816
- Osf patch: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114828

If you are missing any of the patches it won't work. You can verify that these are installed by checking Outlook.exe, mso.dll and osf.dll to make sure they are at 15.0.4805.XXXX. 
If anything is not updated, it will not work

Comment: Thank you so much!